# Ubuntu 18.04 Apache2 not working - Libexec folder not found

Tags: server, 18.04, apache2, shared-library

I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to install LAMP onto it. When I run `sudo apt install apache2` the build failed with errors:

`Failed To Start The Apache HTTP server`

After doing some digging, the error that is happening is that I have no `/usr/local/libexec` folder, so when `apache2.conf` tries to load all of the modules, it throws an error saying `No such file or directory`

`Cannot load libexec/apache22/mod_authn_file.so into server: /usr/local/libexec/apache22/mod_authn_file.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How did this happen, and what is the solution to fix it?